# How to make Predictive text in custom keyboard in iOS 8

Tags: swift, ios8, custom-keyboard

I am developing a custom keyboard and I want to add predictive text in it 
Please help me with these questions...

1. How can I make predictive text using UILexicon?

   2. Do I need a lexical database to make predictive text or work with UILexicon ?
   3. Does UILexicon work with any language?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-c UILexicon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916369/objective-c-uilexicon)

Comment: @rickster I believe a swift example is what Taha is looking for.

Comment: I believe this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26202009/using-uilexicon-to-implement-autocorrect-in-ios-8-keyboard-extension

Comment: Ah, that's a much better answer anyway. (It doesn't matter whether you're talking Swift, ObjC, or building your own ARM machine code bit by bit — these APIs don't do autocorrection for you.)